# Agent connection server error in robot framework while debugging only/Script is running fine

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Getting error while debugging the robot framework script as below-

An internal error occurred during: "Agent connection server".
No enum constant org.rf.ide.core.execution.agent.Status.NOT RUN

[image]

Error details : [ ERROR ] Calling method 'close' of listener 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir17492406270724277522\TestRunnerAgent.py' failed: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine